# fedena or ruby on rails deploy on openshift v3(new openshift)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openshift

**i want to know how to deploy fedena**

---

```
 open source or ruby on rails application on open shift online console version 3 .
```

was done deploy ruby on rails application on older version of open shift now want to know how host on new open shift version 3

Comment: For deploying Ruby applications in general to OpenShift 3, you might start with the post at https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-ruby/